# Valuation ring of finite Krull dimension whose every non-maximal ideal is principal

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory, krull-dimension, local-rings, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a Valuation ring of finite Krull dimension such that every non-maximal ideal i e. every ideal which is not $\mathfrak m$, is principal. Then is $R$ Noetherian i.e. a discrete valuation ring ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{m}=0$, then $R$ is a field.  Otherwise, let $r\in\mathfrak{m}$ be nonzero and let $I=r\mathfrak{m}$.  Then $r\not\in I$ so $I$ is a non-maximal ideal, and hence is principal.  But multiplication by $r$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules from $\mathfrak{m}$ to $I$, so this means $\mathfrak{m}$ is principal as well.  Thus every ideal in $R$ is principal and $R$ is Noetherian.

Comment: Ah ... that was easy ... what do you think would happen if I only required that all non-maximal radical ideals are principal ?

Comment: If the value group is $\mathbb{Q}$, there are no nonzero non-maximal primes.

Comment: Yes yes ... I realized we can get counterexample with Value group a subgroup of real line but not the integers ... what if I want all non-maximal radical ideals to be principal ?

Comment: Radical ideals are the same as prime ideals in a valuation ring.  (An ideal is radical iff it is the intersection of all prime ideals that contain it, but an intersection of a chain of prime ideals is prime.)

Comment: Ah right ... thanks ... in your answer you only use that $R$ is local and integral domain ... how much can any of these two properties be relaxed you think ?

Comment: If $(R, \mathfrak m)$ is local with finitely generated maximal ideal, then for every $r\in \mathfrak m$, $r \mathfrak m \ne \mathfrak m$ by NAK lemma, so $r \mathfrak m$ is principal ... unfortunately this alone doesn't get us that $\mathfrak m$ is principal ...